# Celery PeriodicTask arguments

Tags: python, celery, django-celery

How can I change arguments passed to Celery programmatically? What do I have to change in the following code:

```
from celery.task import PeriodicTask

class MyTask(PeriodicTask):
    run_every = timedelta(seconds=1)
    value = ''
    def run(self, **kwargs):
        print 'Passed value %s' % value
```

I'd like to be able to change the value property during application lifetime. The value will be probably a dictionary, but I doubt if it changes anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you want to change the arguments? Who will pass the arguments each time? The run method is called by the Scheduler upon the specified schedule times.

You can simply read the 'value' from a database or whatever.

```
def run(self, **kwargs):
    value = get_value_from_database()
    print 'Passed value %s' % value
```

Otherwise - you might need to create your custom Scheduler class as described here: http://celery.github.com/celery/userguide/periodic-tasks.html#using-custom-scheduler-classes, and override some of its methods..

Comment: It's just a simple dictionary. Do I really have to create another table and read it from a database?

Comment: The run() method is invoked by the Scheduler. So you should either customize the Scheduler class, or simply read the value in run() from some persistence media - DB, File, Cache, etc.

Comment: It can be useful to have a single task and call it at noon with one parameter and at midnight with another parameter, to have a single implementation with configurable behavior.